# DWQA Plugin filters not working for logged in users

Tags: plugins

I am using the DWQA plugin in my wordpress site : http://getlegal.co.in
But I am facing a problem. The filters in the plugin such as page navigation, category selection etc don't work for a logged in user whereas they function perfectly fine for a non logged in user.
I think there is some problem with the ajax calling.
Is there any code in wp-admin/admin-ajax.php and wp-admin/includes/ajax-functions.php which differentiates the way ajax calling is done for logged in and logged out users ?

[image: When user is not logged in]

[image: When user is logged in]

Comment: Please contact the plugin author for support. Support for third party plugins is off topic

Comment: The question which I have asked is not related to the plugin.Please read the quesiton.